# correlated subqueries in duckdb

Tags: sql, duckdb

I'm writing this correlated subquery in duckdb and I cant figure out why its not working. can someone explain why? Many thanks!

```
select 
o.__policy, 
o.__timestamp,
q.__filename as lastquotefile
from b_n_f b
left join q_n_f q
    on b.__policy = q.__policy
where lastquotefile = (
    select __filename
    from QUOTE_LIST sub 
    where b_n_f.__policy = sub.__policy
    limit 1
)
```

The error is:

```
BinderException: Binder Error: Referenced table "b_n_f" not found!
Candidate tables: "sub"
```

Comment: There is no `b_n_f` any longer, you gave it the alias`b`. So, `where b.__policy = sub.__policy`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner nope thats not it, it doesnt work either.

Comment: Then, what is the error message now?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, same error

Comment: `table "b_n_f" not found`??? Then there simply is no table `table `b_n_f` in your database.

Comment: Is there a column `lastquotefile ` in one of the tables, by the way? `WHERE` happens before `SELECT`, so you cannot use aliases defined in the select clause in the where clause.

Comment: This is a strange condition anyway ("look at all the policy's files, pick one arbitrarily and if that happens to be a match, show the row, else not").

Comment: If `lastquotefile` is supposed to be `q.__filename`, then this is also a strange join ("outer join q, but then dismiss a possibly outer joined row, because after joining I want one particular __filename" - the `__filename` in an outer joined row is null, of course, so this becomes an inner join implicitly).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I tried defining the table manually. That didnt work either. Originally I defined it as a CTE.

Comment: So, `b_n_f` is not a table, but a CTE? I don't see any CTE in your query.

Comment: I tried both ways, the cte wasn't included here cos it had some column names that I hadn't removed. But the things is. If I just run it with the where statement part completely removed, everything runs fine. @ThorstenKettner

Comment: Weird. So, if you add the `WHERE` clause with the subquery and there is no `b_n_f` mentioned in it, because you replaced it with `b`, the DBMS still complains about `b_n_f` being unknown suddenly. That makes no sense. Either you made a mistake or the DBMS is buggy. (I assume here that you replaced `where lastquotefile` with `where q.__filename` or there really is a column `lastquotefile` in one of the tables. As long as you leave errors in your query, it won't run, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there are two syntax erros in your query:

- You cannot access the `b_n_f` in your subquery, because you gave this table an alias and it is known now as `b` to the DBMS.
- You cannot use an alias defined in the `SELECT` clause in your `WHERE` clause, because `SELECT` happens after `WHERE`.

Moreover, you are using a table alias `o`, but in your `FROM` clause there is only `b` and `q`. I suppose this is a typo and `o` is `b` actually.

This is the syntactically corrected query:

```
select 
  b.__policy, 
  b.__timestamp,
  q.__filename as lastquotefile
from b_n_f b
left join q_n_f q on q.__policy = b.__policy
where q.__filename = 
(
  select sub.__filename
  from quote_list sub 
  where sub.__policy = b.__policy
  limit 1
);
```

As also mentioned in the request comments, this query seems semantically wrong. Why outer join, when you dismiss all outer joined rows? Either make this inner join explicit or move the `WHERE` clause into the `ON` clause.

And selecting an arbitrary row in your subquery leads to undeterministic results. Whether and how many result rows you get is left to chance.